# If label's text width is greater than total width of its container then show sub-string using intelligence of pixels

Tags: c#, html, css

I want to do this : If label's text width  is greater than total width of its container 
then show sub-string of the label rather than showing the full label's text.
In c# : currently am using following Code

```
 if (SensorType.Text.Length >= 25) {
    SensorType.Text = SensorType.Text.Substring(0, 20) + "...";
}
```

its working but it ignore pixels or Area of Specific .div
is there any thing to sense div pixels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with PURE CSS...

just set

```
overflow:hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

enjoy

Comment: Ye, Eclipse (and, some time ago, Firebug) too fails to recognize new CSS3 and HTML5 attributes... so you get errors in IDE, but they work in (modern) browsers ;)